# how can I reach my Sanity Studio under a sub route of my NextJs application?

Tags: vercel, sanity, next.js13

How can I use Studio by Sanity v3 as a subroute in NextJs V13 if I have the following folder structure?

```
├── My Application
│   ├── pages
│   └── app
│   ├── src
│   └── studio
│       ├── schema
│       └── ...
```

So that I can access it at the end at https://example.com/studio.

I have already created the following path under sanity.config.js:

```
export default defineConfig({
  name: 'default',
  title: 'ExpandedTemplate',
  basePath: '/studio',
....
)}
```

Under Vercel.json I have stored a redirect.

```
{
  "rewrites": [
    { "source": "/studio/(.*)", "destination": "/studio/index.html" }
  ]
}
```

Does anyone have a good tutorial for this? Blog or possible solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem with next-sanity.

For this I have taken over the folder structure as follows:

```html
├── My Application
│   ├── pages
│       └── studio
│           └── [[...index.js]]
│   ├── sanity.config.js
│   ├── app
│   ├── src
│   └── studio
│       ├── schema
│       └── ...
```

For this I installed sanity again on the main path in package.json and created the sanity.config.js in the main folder.
Here I simply access the schemas from my origin studio under ./studio/schema.

Under pages is the studio route with [[...index]].jsx where the new studio is served up.

So you can access studio under https://example.com/studio.

Or in development you still can access the studio when you navigate in the "origin" studio folder and hit *npx sanity start*, so It will serve up under localhost:3333.

In the [[...index]].jsx File I use the next-sanity package as follow:

```html
import Head from "next/head";
import { NextStudio } from "next-sanity/studio";
import { metadata } from "next-sanity/studio/metadata";

import config from "sanity.config";

export default function StudioPage() {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        {Object.entries(metadata).map(([key, value]) => (
          <meta key={key} name={key} content={value} />
        ))}
      </Head>
      <NextStudio config={config} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Here are some Blogs & Videos:

- https://levelup.gitconnected.com/embed-sanity-studio-v3-in-a-next-js-12-app-d5ae85f77da8
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OcTPaUfay5I&t=1083s

Answer (score 0):

Add a /studio in the url of your website to access your sanitystudio

Comment: It is currently not possible to reach Studio at https://example.com/studio

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the studio route has already been done in the file structure you have provided. I am also working on a blog for nextjs 13 with sanity.

Here is how you can access your studio.

```
http://localhost:3000/studio
```

Answer (score 0):

For nextjs 14 using app router:

Make a sanity.config.ts (.js) file in the root dir of the nextjs app with similar configuration to that in the sanity studio, adding a new key called basePath

```
// ./sanity.config.js
import {defineConfig} from 'sanity'
import {deskTool} from 'sanity/desk'

import {schemaTypes} from './sanity/schema'

const projectId = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_PROJECT_ID!
const dataset = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_DATASET!

export default defineConfig({
  basePath: '/studio', // <-- important that `basePath` matches the route you're mounting your studio from

  projectId,
  dataset,
  plugins: [deskTool()],
  schema: {
    types: schemaTypes,
  },
})
```

Then, make a dynamic directory for your studio:

```
├── My Application
│   ├── app
│       └── studio
│           └── [[...index.js]]
|                   └──page.jsx
|                   └──Studio.jsx
│       ├── sanity.config.js
│       └── studio
│           ├── schema
│           └── ...
```

Now populate the newly created files with necessary code to run your studio:

```
// app/studio/[[...index]]/page.jsx
import {Studio} from './Studio'

// Ensures the Studio route is statically generated
export const dynamic = 'force-static'

// Set the right `viewport`, `robots` and `referer` meta tags
export {metadata} from 'next-sanity/studio/metadata'
export {viewport} from 'next-sanity/studio/viewport'

export default function StudioPage() {
  return <Studio />
}
```

```
// app/studio/[[...index]]/Studio.jsx
'use client'

import {NextStudio} from 'next-sanity/studio'

import config from '../../../sanity.config'

export function Studio() {
  //  Supports the same props as `import {Studio} from 'sanity'`, `config` is required
  return <NextStudio config={config} />
}
```

and lastly, dont forget to add your app link to the allowed origins in the studio management cors settings

If you launch the development server or deploy your app, go to /studio and you'll find your sanity studio

For more info check the documentation of `next-sanity` [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-sanity#configuring-sanity-studio-on-a-route)